# .LESS CSS failing for IIS 4.5 integrated and classic

Tags: .net, iis, .net-4.5, dotless

I'm getting internal server 500 error when using the latest dotless DLL with a .NET 4.5 integrated or classic application pool.  I currently don't have the 4.0 app pool (installed VS 2012 directly... so is this a 4.5 issue, or is there anothe way to make this work?

Comment: What server version at what OS gets you such error?

Comment: Windows 8 VS 2012, IIS that comes with windows 8 (IIS 8?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to 4.5 integrated mode solved the problem, as well as making sure all LESS files are present, which I was missing one.  Classic was not working for me.